# Does referencing a child object prevent the parent object from being garbage collected in javascript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Say I have an object

```
let a = {
  b: {
    name: "Sugarcane"
  }
}
```

and I do

```
let c = a.b
```

and I later nullify the `a` object like so:

```
a = null
```

does the reference to `b` object by `c` prevent the previous object stored in `a` from being garbage collected in Javascript?

Comment: No, it doesn't. JS objects don't have parents.

Comment: Since the object in `c` doesn't have a reference to the object that was in `a`, there shouldn't be any reason via said object isn't gc'ed.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. It has been bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `no`, as long as there is a reference to the object stored in memory, the GC will not be able to free this object from memory.

When you nullify object `A` it is removed from memory, but this does not affect its properties if they are objects and are stored in another variable.

You are just changing the reference from `A` to `NULL`, but `B` will continue to exist in memory as long as `C` continues to have its reference stored.

`B` will only be removed from memory when `C` is nullified.

```js
let a = {
    b: {
        name: "Sugarcane"
    }
};

let c = a.b;

a = null;

console.log(
    "A value: ", a,
    "\nC value:", c,
    "\nC.name value:", c.name
);
```